# i3-2350M at 2.30 GHz vs i7-3517U at 3 GHz

Tags: cpu

I am a video editor and render lots of videos. My current processor is an [**i3-2350M**](http://ark.intel.com/products/53438/Intel-Core-i3-2350M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_30-GHz) with 2 cores and 4 threads running at 2.30 GHz. It takes absolutely forever to render videos. I'm looking to get an [**i7-3517U**](http://ark.intel.com/products/65714/Intel-Core-i7-3517U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz) computer, but the computer I have my eye on has 2 cores and 4 threads running at 1.90 GHz, and its maximum turbo frequency is 3 GHz. Is it worth it getting that computer, and will it render videos any faster? I use sony vegas pro to render.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the cache size or number of cores more important when weighing CPU performance?](http://superuser.com/questions/317771/is-the-cache-size-or-number-of-cores-more-important-when-weighing-cpu-performanc), [Is a higher core count or higher clock speed more beneficial to a computer's performance?](http://superuser.com/questions/324487/is-a-higher-core-count-or-higher-clock-speed-more-beneficial-to-a-computers-per), or [CPU Cores: The more the better?](http://superuser.com/questions/2489/cpu-cores-the-more-the-better).

Comment: Core i3s and i5s usually have 2 cores + HT. A 'consumer' non EE core i7 has 4 and HT, so essentially runs 8 threads (EE cores are essentially a whole different line with some similarities with xeons). However, there's just so many possible bottlenecks with video that you may be comparing apples and oranges, when what you need to be looking at are durians.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to specify what software are you using to render videos.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu you're right. I have misunderstood him.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i7 will be faster than your i3. And I don't think there are quad i3s, it may be dual core with four threads.

Video rendering is also assisted by your GPU if software you use supports it.

You should really be precise which i3 and which i7 are you looking at.

In the end it all depends on your usage. If you render videos for 4-5 hours, 30 mins may not be much of a difference to justify the cost, but if you render for a week, a full day might be.

EDIT

Those are both mobile processors and they will be underpowered compared to desktop versions. If you are looking for mobile solution I suggest i7-3612QM, four cores, eight threads. You can probably get a laptop for arround 800-900$. If your budget allows it get fourth generation multithreaded i7. Or if mobilizy is not an issue get a desktop.