# Is too big cache a bad idea?

Tags: performance, xeon, cpu-cache

I am going to pack a new computer for myself and I thought about Xeon series as main processor. Xeons tend to have very big caches even up to 32MB. And here is a question:

Is it a big advantage to have a big cache in everyday application? How does it impact on games, CAD drawings, browsers etc?

Comment: Also see: [Is the cache size or number of cores more important when weighing CPU performance?](http://superuser.com/questions/317771/is-the-cache-size-or-number-of-cores-more-important-when-weighing-cpu-performanc?rq=1).  Hardware recommendation requests are off-topic for SU.

Comment: Just don't get the larger cache instead of more general improvements such as more RAM or faster HDD.

Answer (score 4):

There's not really a downside to having a large cache. At worst, it'll be populated by stale data which didn't get used.

Comment: however I heard that storing data to cache can use a lot of time. Is it true?

Comment: Not really. Caches only hold a subset of data, and the contents are managed algorithmically. Things will be inserted/evicted from cache as needed. The only real difference would be some cache vs. no cache. (And no cache would really hurt).

Comment: Cache is faster than any other form of storage, and it is filled as data is loaded, so no, not really.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** It depends on the program.

---

Let's take a look first at pro's and con's of big caches:

Pro's:

Bigger cache means less cache misses. Cache misses are expensive, time-wise.

Con's:

Bigger caches are slower per access, because. (more transistors, more has to be transferred on cache miss etc.) That is why there even are caches, and multiple levels of them. (Otherwise, why not just use the RAM directly, right ;-) )

---

In essence, **it depends on your program**, but programs tend to use lots of data nowadays, so bigger cache may be better.

For example, I am into Data Mining. Training models often means repeatedly iterating over big datasets. I imagine a bigger cache might help here, if it means I get significantly less cache misses.

While I don't know about CAD programs, I would imagine modern ones transfer a lot of work load onto the graphics card. The cache size doesn't make a difference here (I think).

Comment: Keep in mind, in this case the OP is asking about CPU cache (L1, L2, L3), not IO cache. CPU cache is used for the CPUs own mechanics like time slicing/context switching, out of order execution, speculative branching and execution, etc. what you are describing is IO caching on a rather large scale, so they are quite different usecases.

Comment: @FrankThomas But isn't the CPU cache used for that as well?

Comment: no, there just isn't enough room, because cache is very expensive, as it does ops on the nanosecond scale. I'm only really referring to your statements about data analysis. content data is just too big and doesn't doesn't usually get reread often enough while it is still cache-resident to make a small short-lived cache benifecial. RAM caching however is great for what you are doing, since it focuses on the largest bottleneck (external storage access time) and has lots of room to store even large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get huge performance improvement relatively to Core i7 processor with same amount of cores and similar clock.

Xeon CPUs are have advantages like these:

- ECC memory controller
- PAE - more memory support (like 768GB instead of 64GB)
- more cores in some models
- more cache in some models
- more PCI express lanes in some models
- support for multiple CPU configurations

Some applications can use higher L3 cache efficiently, but it depends on how application was written. In 3D applications you will not see difference between 8MB and 20MB cache.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a huge advantage, but it is typically a rule of thumb that the more cache, the better the performance. Go ahead and max out the available cache.